# proper naming convention for junit test methods

Tags: testing, methods, junit, naming

What is the proper naming convention for java junits test methods.

public void testServiceName_NullValue()
           or
public void testServiceName_nullValue()

any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no convention. I personally prefer something that respects the Java naming conventions (no underscore), and that starts with should: `public void shouldThrowWhenNullArgument()`, `public void shouldReturnTrueWhenValidArgument()`, etc. I like when there is a prefix like should or test that allows identifying test methods from production methods when searching or calling the call hierarchy in the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't seen a standard, unlike general coding (e.g. Google's). In my team, though, we decided that the test name should very clearly tell what it does even if the resulting name is much longer than the usual method name. The resulting names won't be too long in the end, because a test should focus on one and only one thing. Otherwise, you should rethink your test's scope or your unit's design.

Concretely, we tend to follow the convention *if/whenConditionThenExpectedState/Behavior*. We omit the *test* prefix which today is unnecessary and doesn't add value to the name.

Comment: Personally, I tend to use underscores, for example methodName_should_throw_exception_if_value_is_null(). The idea is simply that noone ever calls the method by hand, the only time you actually see it is when the test fails, so making it even more readable beats traditional naming conventions.